# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load "places_impl" google maps api with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my `Java Spring MVC web application`, I am trying to load the `google map` with multiple locations and an option to set a location using the `Places API`.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="map-search">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="searchNear" id="searchNear" value="" class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="searchNear" class="searchNear active"></label>
        <button id="memberSearch" class="btn btn-defaults btn-group search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
```

I also have the following scripts:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=googleAPIKey&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-path/js/custom-scripts.js"></script>
```

Inside my custom-scripts.js, I have the following code:

```
 function initAutocomplete() {
     $.getJSON('/smartwcm-web/get-locations', function(data) 
     {
            const obj = data;
            var locations = obj.locations.map(({info, latitude, longitude}) => [info, latitude, longitude]);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.0243206, -96.6745042),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
        });

    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          (document.getElementById("searchNear")),
          {types: ["geocode"]});

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
 }


    $(document).on( 'click','a[id^="showMap-"]', function(event) {
        jQuery("#pageLoading").show();
        event.preventDefault();
        var arr = this.id.split('-');
        var count = arr[1];
        var latVal = +$("#lat-"+count).val();
        var lonVal = +$("#lon-"+count).val();
        var titleVal = $("#info-"+count).val();
        var newCenter = {lat: latVal, lng: lonVal};
        // The map, centered at newCenter
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: newCenter, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy'});
        // The marker, positioned at newCenter
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: newCenter, map: map, title: titleVal});
        jQuery("#pageLoading").hide();
    });

    if((jQuery("#searchNear").val()).length == 0)
    {
        if(jQuery("#userLocation").length)
        {
            jQuery("#searchNear").val(jQuery("#userLocation").val());
            var cachedLoc = jQuery("#userLocation").val();
            var loc_array = "";
            if(cachedLoc.indexOf(',') != -1)
            {
                loc_array = cachedLoc.split(',');
            }
            else
            {
                loc_array = cachedLoc.split(' ');
            }
            jQuery("#postal_code").val('');
            if(loc_array[2] && $.isNumeric(loc_array[2]))
            {
                jQuery("#postal_code").val(loc_array[2].trim());
            }
        }
    }

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
      street_number: "short_name",
      route: "long_name",
      locality: "long_name",
      administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
      country: "long_name",
      postal_code: "short_name"
    };

    /*function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          *//** @type {!HTMLInputElement} *//*(document.getElementById("searchNear")),
          {types: ["geocode"]});

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
    }*/

    function fillInAddress() {
      // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = "";
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }

      // Get each component of the address from the place details
      // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
    }
```

The code works for me mostly, but occasionally I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load "places_impl" google maps api with javascript

I am not sure why this error is occurring and not occurring always. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You could run this command below your codes.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your API javascript loads after the whole code in some cases where you get that error.

Remove that async defer from map javascript api and error should not come

make it like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=googleAPIKey&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the param callback=initAutocomplete and async in the final . Now call the function initAutocomplete() in the final line.